# React Native - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Token M when using a separate Express API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a separate express server running on localhost:3000 with mock data. I've confirmed that this server works as expected by testing api endpoints in a browser. I'm then using redux to make an api call to my express server to add this mock data into my RN project. I'm also using redux middleware similar to [this boilerplate](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html).

Here's the error I see. My first thought is why do I see localhost:8081 in the error and not localhost:3000?

If I log the error in the reducer, I see "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0(…)"

[image]

Here's my reducer code. `{apiUrl}/v1/accounts` is the same as `http://localhost:3000/v1/accounts`

In the console I confirm that the action `TEST_MOCKS_REQUEST`runs and then the reducer get the action `TEST_MOCKS_FAILURE`. What am I not seeing?

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const TEST_MOCKS_REQUEST = 'TEST_MOCKS_REQUEST';
const TEST_MOCKS_SUCCESS = 'TEST_MOCKS_SUCCESS';
const TEST_MOCKS_FAILURE = 'TEST_MOCKS_FAILURE';

import { CALL_API } from 'api-middleware';
import { apiUrl } from './utils/clientHelpers';


export default function reducer(state = fromJS({ }), action) {

 console.log('state in test reducer', state.toJS(), action)
  switch (action.type) {

    case TEST_MOCKS_REQUEST: {

      return state
        .removeIn(['test','errors'])
        .removeIn(['test','data'])
        .setIn(['test','loading'], true);
    }

    case TEST_MOCKS_SUCCESS: {
      const { data } = action;

      return state
        .removeIn(['test','loading'])
        .removeIn(['test','errors'])
        .setIn(['test','data'], data);
    }

    case TEST_MOCKS_FAILURE: {
      const { error } = action;

      return state
        .removeIn(['test','loading'])
        .removeIn(['test','data'])
        .setIn(['test','errors'], error);
    }

    default:
      return fromJS(state);
  }

}

export function loadMock() {
 console.log('load mock called', apiUrl)

  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
      [CALL_API]: {
        types: [
          TEST_MOCKS_REQUEST,
          TEST_MOCKS_SUCCESS,
          TEST_MOCKS_FAILURE
        ],
        callAPI: (client) => client.get(`${apiUrl}/v1/accounts`),
        isLoading: state => state.testing.hasIn(['test','loading']),
        getLoadingPromise: state => state.testing.getIn(['test','loading']),
        isLoaded: state => state.testing.hasIn(['test','data']),
        getResourceFromState: state => state.testing.getIn(['test','data']),
      }
    });
 }
  }
```

Comment: What is ur apis's response body? make sure that it is a vlid json and try again. I used to see this error when my api return something non-json, and I didn't catch the error and reject.

Comment: @EricHua23 I should have put this as an update. I suspected this. It seems to be valid json when I hit end points in the browser however I have another library creating the actual json. So, I checked this by hardcoding a very simple res.json({"test":"123"}) and that did work. So, I think we're onto something. I need to look deeper into the library creating the json. Thanks for commenting!